# Protect API from misuse

Tags: javascript, html, api

I have created a game API and that API will be consumed by fully client side javascript+html5 application which is in a different domain.

I manage to fix all CORS problems and it is working fine.

That API has a method to submit user score. Once the user finishes the game, the javascript app will submit the final score to the API.

But the problem  is it secure to do that? Because some users can misuse the API to send fake scores to the server.

On other hand is it secure to create that web app fully client side to generate score?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is it secure to take data from the client and trust it on the server?

Comment: If a client side script is generating a score and sending it via an API to your server, then no - it's not secure. Anybody could manipulate that and create their own score to send instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple "submit score" API for a game that runs fully client-side cannot be secured; consider the sums game companies spend trying to "secure" their games against copyright infringement, yet those protections are regularly brushed aside.

If the game core is sufficiently deterministic, you can solve the problem by having the client submit a transcript of their actions and then processing that transcript (re-running the game core server-side) to determine the actual score.  As a bonus, you're also halfway to enabling other players to watch replays of high scorers' games as well: let them download the transcript and re-run the game core using the transcript instead of live player input (and flag obvious cheese for your moderators, naturally).

If the game depends heavily on hidden information (such as cards that are face-down or in an undealt stack) you need to keep that information off the client's machine entirely, and use API calls to reveal things as the player discovers them.  Otherwise, the player can "magically" make the correct decision when confronted with a dilemma.

If the game depends heavily on player dexterity, you're up a rather sewage-laden creek: it ultimately degenerates into the same problem as detecting aimbots, wallhacks and the like in multiplayer first-person shooters, which has turned into an [arms race](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-cheat_software#Anti-cheating_methods_and_limitations) comparable to the virus/antivirus arms race.